# Split logs from cron jobs

Tags: logs, cron

I currently have a log file which has no limit and I was hoping to be able to set up a cron job that would start writing to a new file so it doesn't get too big. Would that be possible? So it would keep the old one with a date and start a new one, with a 10MB size limit.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is common enough that there's a whole program to do that, [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate), which can also zip the old files, only keep the last X, and pretty much most things you could reasonably want to do with old logfiles.

Comment: I was actually just thinking of writing a script to rename the file and set a cron job to run it once a month

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `logrotate`. Hard not to find that with a short look at your favorite search engine.

Comment: It may be hard if you call it “casting up cron jobs” (I have no idea what that's supposed to mean).